# How to match only part of URL and redirect URL with parameters in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a number of links with similar structure:

```
example.com/index.php/path/some-path/some-subpath?parameter=1
```

Which I want to redirect just to `example.com/category/`

But I want to match only the URL-path, ie. `/index.php/path/some-path/some-subpath`, because the query parameter is irrelevant.

I have tried the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php/path/some-path/some-subpath?parameter=\dd\? /category/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You state that the "query parameter is irrelevant", yet you are trying to check for it in your code example - why? Must the `parameter=` part be present, but the _value_ does not matter? Or can the query string be ignored altogether?

Comment: @w3dk complete part '?parameter=value' can be ignoner, but URL should be rewritten. If I use redirect 301 only, I don't get URL rewritten to domain.com/category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query string is irrelevant then it can simply be ignored. (You can't match the query string anyway with the `RewriteRule` directive.)

Try the following in your root .htaccess file to *redirect* the request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/path/some-path/some-subpath$ /category/? [L,R=301]
```

In per-directory .htaccess files, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has the directory-prefix removed. In other words, it does not start with a slash, `^index.php....` instead of `^/index.php....`.

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution is required in order to remove the query string (if any) from the request. Otherwise `parameter=1` will be passed through and appended to the target URL.

This will match *any* query string, including an empty one.

Comment: @wkd, what if I want to rewrite this URL to root, should I use only '/'?

Comment: Yes, just use `/?`. You'll need to clear your browser cache if you have previously tested the rule above. 301 redirects are cached by the browser. For this reason it is often a good idea to test with 302 (temporary) redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @MrWhite did not worked for me. Here is what is working with my Wordpress site.

Example:

```
OLD URL: http://website.com/xxx/yyy/picture.png
NEW URL: http://website.com/wp-content/picture.png
```

So, I want to replace **/xxx/yyy/** with the normal **/wp-content/** path of WordPress.

Put this in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 /xxx/yyy/(.*) http://website.com/wp-content/$1
```